# CakePHP - making XML folder public

Tags: xml, cakephp

how can I give "public access" to files in a folder in the webroot? Ive got a folder: webroot/xml. and if i type in in browser: www.example.com/xml/afile.xml, cakePHP is trying to find a XmlController and sends me an error. But I just want to display the xml file. How can i tell CakePHP not to search for the XmlController, but to simply display my xml files that are located in this folder?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely either something is wrong w/ your mod_rewrite or you're typing the filename/path incorrectly.

Comment: no.. cakePHP tries to route my request to a specific controller... but of course there is no XmlContoller. The files in webroot/xml should be displayes in the browser just like files in webroot/css

Comment: I understood the first time you explained.  Unless you're modifying something to break it, or there's an issue w/ mod_rewrite, or you're typing the name wrong, this works by default with CakePHP and requires no additional code.

Comment: I'm sorry, Dave! cakePHP automatically did that for me, and I really just had a mistake in my URL - embarrassing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP makes all webroot files "public" by default.

If you can't access a file within webroot, check a few things:

- Make sure mod_rewrite is on
- Make sure you're typing the path/filename correctly
- Make sure you have no custom routes (`Config/routes.php`) that would affect that file